# Ajax doesn't work with particular actions

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

My `ajax` request works fine if the url lead to the `index` action but on if it is leading to `calculate` action. On `calculate` it returns the page HTML. What can cause this ?

```
$(function () {
    $("#w0").on("beforeSubmit", function () {
        $.ajax({
            method: "get",
            url: "/site/calculate",
            data: {
                token: 123
            },
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        })
        return false
    })
})

public function actionCalculate($token)
    {
        var_dump(5512312);die;
    }
```

No console errors.

Comment: does to url must be site/index.php?calculate ?

Comment: not enough info , what do you get as response for the request

Comment: HTML of the page. I said it.

Comment: @Sfili_81 I am using prettty URLs, so the variant in my case is the correct one

Comment: And can someone explain why it's -1 ? If you can't solve the problem it doesn't mean that it is not a problem. Maybe it means that you are not so skillable.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling var_dump you are basically making echo command. As a result, your response will automatically set Content-Type: text/html on it.

There is multiple solutions, depends on what you want to have as a result.
If you expecting to receive JSON in the end, just change response type

```
public function actionCalculate($token){
    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return 5512312;
}
```

Comment: `var_dump`-ing number, even without setting json response format is totaly correct. The result in the log will be the number.